# Singular Value Decomposition of Singular Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

$\exists \delta > 0 $ such that whenever $0 < |\varepsilon| < \delta$, $A+\varepsilon I$ is non-singular , for any singular matrix A $\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ .
This is easy to prove. Because det(A+$\varepsilon I$) is a n degree polynomial in $\varepsilon$. It has atmost n roots. So we can choose $\delta$ favourable to us.

Now using this, I tried to determine the SVD of singular matrices.

By considering, $A_\varepsilon : = W_\varepsilon.\Sigma_\varepsilon.V
^*_\varepsilon$

Then if we let $\varepsilon \to 0$, do we end up in getting the SVD of singular matrix???

Comment: Why so much elaboration? No need for limits; in the same way you can always eigendecompose a symmetric matrix, regardless of its invertibility, you can perform SVD on any square matrix.

Comment: i need concrete determination of SVD for singular matrices.

Comment: Sure, so consider the eigendecomposition of $\mathbf A^\top\mathbf A$...

Comment: thats so fyn.. See for non-singular matrix A. $A^*A = UDU^*$ I will set $\Sigma = \sqrt(D), W=U and V^*=\Sigma^{-1}W^*A$. Like this I want to determine the SVD of singular matrices concretely...

Comment: You're not inverting the matrix, so you can certainly consider the eigendecomposition. It is perfectly fine for a matrix to have a zero eigenvalue, and thus it is also fine for a matrix to have a zero singular value.